# Can't add Testers in Google Play Services

Tags: google-play-services

I am trying to add testers for Google Play Services.

However, whenever I use any of my gmail accounts, e.g. fbloggs@googlemail.com / fbloggs@gmail.com, it always returns this message :

The following email addresses could not be added because they are not Google accounts or have not enabled Google+: fbloggs@googlemail.com

I definitely have enabled Google+ because when I go to plus.google.com with this account, I can see Google+ content.

What else do I need to do?